# Python Django template rendering from views gives me a too many values to unpack error

Tags: python, django

I have a function in views.py that renders the template in template.html shown below:

views.py

```
def example(request):
    context_dict = {
        'form_1': Step1Form,
        'form_2': Step2Form,
        'form_3': Step3Form,
    }
    return render(request, 'example/template.html', context_dict)
```

template.html

```
<form method="GET" action="/example/">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div>
                    {% for field in form_1 %}
                        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label><br>
                        {{ field }}<br>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </form>
<form method="GET" action="/example/">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div>
                    {% for field in form_2 %}
                        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label><br>
                        {{ field }}<br>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </form>
<form method="GET" action="/example/">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div>
                    {% for field in form_3 %}
                        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label><br>
                        {{ field }}<br>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </form>
```

But for some reason when I load the template, I get the error:

> ValueError at /example/
>   too many values to unpack (expected 2)

The template will load if the field tag in the third form is gone. The context dictionary and rendering doesn't look any different from other ones that I've seen so I don't know what's causing the problem.

Comment: Could you share your forms.py and the full code of your views.py?

Comment: That is the full views.py. I don't think the forms.py is relevant.

Comment: please can we have the full traceback? Or at the very least, an indication of which line in which file(of yours) is leading to the error.

Comment: oh, and that can't be the "full views.py", because it doesn't define what `Step1Form` etc are. It seems from your description that something may be amiss with `Step3Form` - but we have no idea what it is.

Comment: It looks to me like your iteration is the problem. I would expect something like "{% for field in form.fields %}"

Answer (score 0):

in your views.py, you seem to be passing the form class rather than an instance of the form. Maybe the answer is to call the class and make an instance for the template to render, by adding ().  As long as these are unbound forms you can probably get away with:

```
context = { 'form_1': Step1Form(),
            'form_2': Step2Form(),
            'form_3': Step3Form()}
```

Answer (score -1):

The value error maybe caused because the template cannot render the forms directly as they are passed as `context_dict`. So here is my solution:

**views.py**

```
def example(request):
    context_dict = {
        'form_1': Step1Form,
        'form_2': Step2Form,
        'form_3': Step3Form,
    }
    return render(request, 'example/template.html', {'context_dict':context_dict})
```

**template**

```
<form method="GET" action="/example/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                {% for field in context_dict.form_1 %}
                    <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label><br>
                    {{ field }}<br>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </form>
    <form method="GET" action="/example/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                {% for field in context_dict.form_2 %}
                    <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label><br>
                    {{ field }}<br>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </form>
    <form method="GET" action="/example/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                {% for field in context_dict.form_3 %}
                    <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label><br>
                    {{ field }}<br>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </form>
```